# Liferay portal 6.2 Errror - Could not execute JDBC batch update; SQL [insert into DLFileRank -

Tags: performance, jdbc, liferay, liferay-6, catalina.out

In  Linux Centos, I started up my liferay portal 6.2 ce-ga2. Every things were okay, but I saw these erorrs in catalina.out log file:

```
    23:31:05,917 ERROR [http-bio-80-exec-404][status_jsp:750] org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update; SQL [insert into DLFileRank (groupId, companyId, userId, createDate, fileEntryId, active_, fileRankId) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; constraint ; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update; SQL [insert into DLFileRank (groupId, companyId, userId, createDate, fileEntryId, active_, fileRankId) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; constraint ; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:637)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:793)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:664)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.processCommit(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:82)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:70)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy199.getFileAsStream(Unknown Source)
at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFileAsStream(DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.java:553)
at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.model.impl.DLFileVersionImpl.getContentStream(DLFileVersionImpl.java:54)
at com.liferay.portal.repository.liferayrepository.model.LiferayFileVersion.getContentStream(LiferayFileVersion.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.webserver.WebServerServlet.sendFile(WebServerServlet.java:986)
at com.liferay.portal.webserver.WebServerServlet.service(WebServerServlet.java:259)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:46)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:263)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter.processFilter(NtlmPostFilter.java:83)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:88)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:297)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656)
... 70 more
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '10157-37238-102948' for key 'IX_38F0315'
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:2054)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1467)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1135)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
... 78 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '10157-37238-102948' for key 'IX_38F0315'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1040)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:2006)
... 82 more
```

How can I solve this issue?

Although I set this variablese in setenv.sh :

```
    CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true  -Dorg.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES=false -Duser.timezone=GMT -Xms1024m -Xmx5110m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"

export JRE_HOME="/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/"
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx4096m -Xms2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

But I don't know where in liferay portal causes to happenning this event!!!!!!

Please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: If you look at the stack trace, it says that the root problem is a constraint violation when a batch insert is attempted to the `DLFileRank` table. Further down, it says `Duplicate entry '10157-37238-102948' for key 'IX_38F0315'`, so it seems like a unique constraint is being violated. What part of your code is doing the insert?

Comment: If your question has been answered by Prakash K, please consider accepting it (and upvote). Also, please link your crossposts in the future. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site describes the rationale and the etiquette behind this.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the stack-trace this clearly is a data-integrity issue.

The unique index which is being violated here is on `DLFileRank` table as per [`indexes.sql`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/sql/indexes.sql#L270):

```
create index IX_38F0315 on DLFileRank (companyId, userId, fileEntryId);
```

It is affecting the particular user (id=37238) for this file (id=102948), may be it should have been an `UPDATE`.

### What to do

#### Approach-I

It might have been due to stale cache (though unlikely), try clearing the db-cache & Server cache from `Control Panel --> Server Administration`.

#### Approach-II

If you want you can disable the file-rank feature altogather:

```
#
# Set this to true to enable file rank for document library files.
#
dl.file.rank.enabled=true (make this false)
```

File rank is basically a convenience feature for Users to access their most recently viewed documents. So every time a user accesses a document it would trigger an update in the `DLFileRank` table depending upon your configuration.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have another question , if I make "false" this statement dl.file.rank.enabled it's not harmful for my liferay portal???????

Comment: Not harmful. As i said it is a convenience feature so the feature for recent documents won't work as expected. Will not affect the portal as a whole.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: In stackoverflow we say thanks by clicking on an upward arrow ... :-) hehe